# How to Add Multiple Lines to Text File in Java (at different times?)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a library where all the book's info (author and title) are in a text file. I can successfully add one book to the text file, but if I try to add a new book, it deletes the previous book as well... if anyone could help that would be really appreciated!

```
String theTitle = bookTitleW.getText().toString();
String theAuthor = bookAuthorW.getText().toString();

try {
    BufferedWriter readMe = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("allBooks.txt"));
    readMe.write(theTitle + "," + theAuthor);
    readMe.newLine();
    readMe.close();
} catch (IOException c) {
    c.printStackTrace();
}
```

It prints out the inputted title and author like expected, but will just rewrite over the old input if any new input is added.

Comment: Are you familiar with [java.io.RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `append` flag as `true` to the writer.

```
BufferedWriter readMe = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("allBooks.txt", true));
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here.

First, when you open a `FileWriter` on a file, by default, it does, indeed, recreate the file.

There is the option of:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter('thefile.txt', true);
```

This will open the file in Append mode, which means it starts at the end of the file, rather than recreating it. This allows you to, over time, build a file up.

However, make no mistake, without the append flag, the FileWriter will DESTROY any existing file. It does not "start at the beginning". So, you can't use a FileWriter to change an existing file. You either recreate it entirely, or append to it.

A simple example of text editor is a program that reads in the entire file, changes it, and then writes the entire file back out.

Java has another class, `RandomAccessFile`, which allows you to both read, and write, an existing file in place. But using a RandomAccessFile with a text file is notoriously difficult, if for no other reason than modern encoding methods of text. Add in the vary lengths of lines also makes it more difficult.

RandomAccessFiles work easier with a record who's length is known in advance.